# vuejs emit from soket.io trouble

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io-1.0

I'm trying to get data from the server with the socket.
But vue does not fill the table, because the client has an array, and the server returns objects.

serverside

```
...
const r = require('rethinkdb');
const io = socketIO(server);
r.connect(db)  
    .then(conn => {
        io.on('connection', (client) => {
             r.table('messages')
                 .run(conn)
                 .then(cursor => {
                     cursor.each((err, message) => {
                         io.sockets.emit('messages', message);
                     });
                 });
```

client- vue

```
<template>
....
 <table>
 <tr>
   <th>name</th>
   <th>message</th>
   <th>date</th>
 </tr>
 <tr v-for="object in objects" :key="object.id">
   <td>{{object.id}}</td>
   <td>{{object.name}}</td>
   <td>{{object.message}}</td>
   <td>{{object.date}}</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
    ...
    <script>     
    export default {
      name: 'App',
      data () {
        return {
          objects: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        send () {
          this.$socket.on('test',message => {
              this.objects = message  
              console.log(message)
              })                      
        }
      }
```

in console:
 [image: info]
but vue needs array of objects:
 [image: error]
myrepo (fullcode)
https://github.com/EvgenJin/REVN_project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just use push on the array.

```
this.$socket.on('test', message => {
    this.objects.push(message)
})
```

Since in the HTML you're expecting an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks. I did so, but when I re-do send () with other parameters (dates filter) , the array is not updated, and new entries are added at the end. Perhaps you need to clear the array

Comment: Solved.in server side cursor.toArray((err,message) instead cursor.each((err, message). work greats by this.objects = message